# Select and Unselect custom button in tableViewCell swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

Custom button in tableViewCell and there is list of item which I want to handle through this button.When click on first button first cell is selecting and when click on second button in tableView cell second cell is selecting but not deselecting first one.Please check my code.

TableViewCell:

```
  var selectCategory: ((Int) -> Void)?
   

    @IBAction func didTapSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
        selectCategory?(sender.tag)
    }
```

CellForRowAt method:

```
cell.buttonRadio.tag = indexPath.row
cell.selectCategory = { num in
     if !self.selectedRows.contains(num) {
                        self.selectedRows.append(num)
                            cell.buttonRadio.setImage(UIImage(named: "radioSelected"), for: .normal)
                            self.buttonLink.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                            self.buttonLink.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(hex: "#453073")
                        for visited in self.selectedRows {
                            if num == visited {
                                cell.buttonRadio.setImage(UIImage(named: "radioSelected"), for: .normal)
                                self.buttonLink.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                                self.buttonLink.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(hex: "#453073")
                            }
                             if num != visited {
                                cell.buttonRadio.setImage(UIImage(named: "radioUnselected"), for: .normal)
                                self.buttonLink.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                                self.buttonLink.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(hex: "#A297B9")
                                self.selectedRows.remove(at: self.selectedRows.firstIndex(of: visited)!)
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Now what is the issue ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan not selecting and deselecting row correctly through custom tableView cell button.Here is something wrong in my code. Like if i'm selecting first item and when click on second item first item still active position.I want when selecting any item i the list the other other item deselect did you get my point?

Comment: There are a lot of unknowns here. Better create and provide a [mre] that reproduces the problem. Without that I doubt someone can spot the error.

Comment: @Shaikh then why you create an array of selected rows `selectedRows` ? why not an `Int` ?

Comment: add implementation for func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) here you could deselect "unselect" first selected cell the indexPath in didDeslectRow is of first cell

Comment: @Sh_Khan the selectRows keep the record of selected Rows and when click on any other button through this array we can deselect the pervious deselected rows and i  Int will not work in this case.